# Xamarin - iOS backgrounding with BT low Energy and TTS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, text-to-speech, btle

I'm working on a proof of concept app. I'm using Xamarin for iOS. The iPhone app runs in the background and watches for particular BTLE devices and speaks using TTS when the signal is at a certain strength. I have TTS working and I can recognize the BTLE devices when the app is in the foreground.

However, I'm having trouble getting either working when the iPhone screen is off. In Android, I'd just use a wake lock, but that appears to not be available in iOS. I tried setting the background modes in the info.plist file for BTLE and sound, but I don't see any processing happen while the unit is suspended. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is just a proof of concept, so I'm only looking at the latest iOS version and I'm interested in even hacky answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using iBeacons or something home grown?

Comment: I'm using [Estimote beacons](http://estimote.com/)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything other than use the CoreLocation Beacon Region Monitoring stuff.   It will wake up your app and call the callbacks.  You probably don't have long to execute the TTS code, and you may still need some audio permissions/settings in the plist, but I don't know those offhand.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create at least one background task `UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask` and end it with `EndBackgroundTask` when you finish transferring your data.

Note that you will have approximately 10 minutes in background. If user switch back to the app the time will be reset.

You might also want to disable application idle timer to prevent the screen to go black when the user doesnt touch it.

Comment: I'm not transferring data, I'm watching for a btle beacon to come in range. This might work for the proof of concept, but I'm going to need more than 10 minutes. Isn't there a way to keep watching for beacons longer than 10 minutes?

Comment: Can't my app get some cycle time when I come in range of a beacon? That kills a lot of uses of btle if you can't.